# Avoiding unnecessarily large IDs in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Recently we decided it would benefit us if the IDs of our Datastore entities weren't soo big. Biggest reason being, we use these IDs in URLs that we'd like to keep nice and short.

Currently, as an example, the IDs of our entities grow like this:

```
id=2
id=2003
id=2004
id=2027
id=2028
id=5002
id=5204
id=6001
id=7534
id=8001
id=10192
id=11306
id=14306
id=16330
id=18306
id=20321
id=41312
id=79306
id=113308
id=113311
etc.
```

As you can see, sometimes the increase is in the tens of thousands.

Now, we could cope with all this hassle by creating a sharded counter big enough to count the number of entities for us and then assign the IDs ourselves, but I would still like it better if the Datastore would assign the keys for us.

Is there any way of telling the Datastore to re-calculate the available IDs, so that next time I'd store an entity, it would get the lowest available ID? They don't need to be sequential in our case.

**UPDATE:**

As @[Amber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber) suggested, we could encode the digits to base62 to have them shorter (at most 11 digits for 64-bit unsigned `int`s).

While this approach is not too bad, it has a few disadvantages. First I'm not sure how good UX it is. Second, some digits would clash with other strings that we currently use in URLs.

As an example:

```
/books/(\d+)(/book-name)?
/books/selection
```

The book with id `26086738530` would have the URLs '/books/selection/book-name' and '/books/selection', clashing with our other page.

Comment: Why not just re-encode the IDs in a more compact base when using them in your URLs? (E.g. base-62)

Comment: @[Amber](http://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber) I've updated the question to show what the problem is with base62.

Comment: In the example you showed there isn't a clash, there would be a clash if the regex for the url would be something like /books/selection/.*

Comment: @[ShayErlichmen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/48387/shay-erlichmen) yes it is: base62(26086738530) = 'selection', and since the '/book-name' part is optional, it '/books/selection' would correspond to the page of the book.

Comment: @AttilaOláh The only way to avoid that is to structure your URL scheme so they're unambiguous.

Comment: @NickJohnson Sure, you're right - unfortunately I'm not the one who gives the final word on URLs. There are UX folks who want to see "short decimal integers" in the URLs, so I won't go with base62 anyway...

Comment: If you're having URLs that people need to type by hand, the UX people might have a point. If they're objecting on strictly cosmetic grounds, I'd push back on them, since your adding complication (and possibly a maintenance burden) to code that otherwise works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a mechanism in the datastore that allows you to control the automatic  id creation.

How many objects do you estimate you will have in the project life time? because long ids seems like an hassle now but might be a necessary anyway when you will have tens of thousands objects in the store.

As goes for the base62, you can route base62 ids thru a different url.

Comment: Ok, true. I'll consider your suggestions, but I think we won't go with base64 for now - if we wanted just to shorten the URLs, we could just use a public URL shortener...

Comment: if you decide to go with public url shortener you can try to use bit.ly which allows you to shorten the urls and have your own domain (free).